# How can I make ToString keep significant numbers with zeros?

Tags: formatting

I would like the output of `ToString` to keep the zeros as in the input, how can I do that?

```
In[145]:= ToString[2.00, InputForm]

Out[145]= "2."
```

**update**

problem solved as follows

```
In[249]:= ToString[NumberForm[2., {1, 2}]]

Out[249]= "2.00"
```

Or, as suggested by @Shin Kim

```
In[257]:= ToString[-2`3]

Out[257]= "-2.00"
```

Now, I would like also to keep the sign - or + if possible, it works with - but with + not

```
In[250]:= ToString[NumberForm[+2., {1, 2}]]

Out[250]= "2.00"
```

Comment: The problem is that Mathematica front end immediately simplifies/rewrites `2.00` to `2.` before even the kernel gets hold of it. If you write `2.00` it becomes `2.`  Even `HoldForm[2.00]` does not prevent this.

Comment: You can, however, play with [NumberForm](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NumberForm.html) to include a specified number of zeros, if that helps.

Comment: @thorimur, yep, that works..Thanks, man! `ToString[NumberForm[2.00, {1, 2}]]`

Comment: You can just do `ToString[NumberForm[2.,{1,2}]]` as   `2.00`  are the same as `2.0` which is the same as `2.`  saves you typing all those extra zeros.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any number you input that has the dot `.` is interpreted as a floating number with the machine precision, unless your input has more digits under the decimal point than the machine precision or you specified the precision. Otherwise zeroes at the end won't really have any effect on the precision.

You can specify the precision of your numeric input via `SetPrecision` or simply by putting  `` ` `` at the end:

```
In[1]:= 2`3 (*also 2.00`3*)

Out[2]= 2.00
```

To turn this into a string with the sign symbol,

```
a = 2`3;
ToString[Sign[a] /. {1 -> "+", -1 -> ""}] <> ToString[a]

(*"+2.00"*)
```